# Running a time.Sleep inside a time.Tick does not honour the Sleep period

Tags: go

I was curious what happens if you run a task periodically, inside a `time.Tick`, but the task is taking **longer** than the ticker.

Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/el7C_bzjpCe) - wait longer to see the output (even though it says "timeout").

In order to simulate that the task is taking longer, I'm using a `time.Sleep`. *To my surprise*, it seems that this `time.Sleep` automatically expires when the new `time.Tick` comes.

Questions:

1. can someone help with an explanation here?
2. what if the task is *really taking longer* **without using a time.Sleep**? What would happen when the new `time.Tick` comes but the previous task did not finish?

Comment: regarding #2, I think the [ticker example](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Ticker) in the docs show a suitable way how to handle tasks that take longer than the ticks specified: you run the task independently from the code that manages it, i.e. where the ticker runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time.Tick` does not affect `time.Sleep`.

You are printing the ticker step time instead of the real time.

Try

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var i int
    c := time.Tick(5 * time.Second)
    for next := range c {
        i++
        fmt.Printf("%d) %v\n", i, next)
        fmt.Printf("%d) %v\n", i, time.Now())
        time.Sleep(8 * time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("%d) finished sleeping\n", i)
    }
}
```